# iphone X remove UITabbarViewController blue highlighting in selected tab

Tags: ios, iphone, swift3, uitabbarcontroller, ios11

[image]

i want to remove blue highlighting in iPhone X(10) while selecting ant of tab from `UITabbarViewController`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can customize it by use property [`tintColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbar/1623460-tintcolor) for specified color only to the tab bar’s items

> **Discussion**
>   Assigning a value to this property applies the specified color only to the tab bar’s items. Even if you do not specify a color, the tab bar may tint items using the tint color of one of its ancestor views. For information on how tinting colors are applied to views in a view hierarchy, see the description of the tintColor property in UIView.

Comment: let me check your suggestion